# How do you run a set of test classes from 1 class

Tags: java, junit

Currently all my tests extend another class that has a @BeforeAll tag but I want this BeforeAll code to be run just once in total for the entirety of the tests instead of once per class

```
@BeforeAll
static void createWriter() throws IOException {
    // create file to be writen to
}

@AfterAll
static void finishFile() throws IOException {
    // end file and create high level metrics
}

@Override
public void testSuccess(ExtensionContext extensionContext, Throwable throwable) {
    // override normal test execution finishes
}
```

Comment: Show some of your code.

Comment: How would a teardown method be run once?

Comment: please take a look at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner-test-suite

Answer (score 1):

You have to run test cases as a test suite. You can use testing framework "**TestNG**" to achieve this functionality.

Use annotations [@BeforeSuite](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) and [@AfterSuite](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html), which will execute once for multiple test classes.

Please check with this [link](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/184) for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any built-in way of doing that. So the simple technical answer would be to use a static boolean flag that tells that method whether the method ran already (or not). Upon the first method execution, that flag gets toggled, and prevents further executions.

But the real answer is: you are probably going down the wrong rabbit hole. Having test classes extend a base class is more of an anti pattern, and to have a *BeforeAll* method that is either too expensive to be called repeatedly, or worse: not idempotent makes things worse. Unit tests should be simple and self explanatory (thus self contained). Inheritance and "run only once" directly violate that requirement.

Comment: I'm extending a base class with the purpose of modifying testSuccess, testFailed, etc methods. The base class doesn't have other parts that are used in the unit test